# Importing excel data in to sql database using php

Tags: php, sql, excel, forms

I am trying to import data from excel sheet to my sql database using the following php code:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "unhrd_fund_balance";


$conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname","$username","$password","$database") or die(mysql_error());


?>

<form name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>



<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {
        $progkey = $filesop[0];
        $grantkey = $filesop[1];
        $TOD = $filesop[2];
        $TDD=$filesop[3];
        $fund=$filesop[4];
        $orderkey=$filesop[5];
        $budget=$filesop[6];
        $precommit=$filesop[7];
        $commit=$filesop[8];
        $actuals=$filesop[9];
        $totalcommit=$filesop[10];
        $availbudget=$filesop[11];

        $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO csv (FUNDED_PROG_KEY, GRANT_KEY, TOD, TDD, FUND, ORDER_KEY, BUDGET_ALLOC, PRE_COMMIT, COMMIT, ACTUALS, TOTAL_COMMIT,AVAILABLE_BUDGET) VALUES ('$progkey', '$grantkey','$TOD','$TDD','$fund','$orderkey','$budget','$precommit','$commit,'$actuals','$totalcommit','$availbudget')");


    }

        if($sql){
            echo "You database has imported successfully";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }
}
?>
```

My SQL database is:

```
CREATE TABLE `fund_balances` (
  `FUNDED_PROG_KEY` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `GRANT_KEY` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `TOD` date NOT NULL,
  `TDD` date NOT NULL,
  `FUND` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `ORDER_KEY` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `BUDGET_ALLOC` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `PRE_COMMIT` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `COMMIT` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `ACTUALS` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `TOTAL_COMMIT` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
  `AVAILABLE_BUDGET` bigint(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am getting the following errors when I attach the xlsx file and click on submit in the form:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 36
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 37
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 38
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 39
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 40
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 8 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 41
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 43
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 11 in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Web/Form1.php on line 44

Comment: You're mixing two things up. It sounds like you're trying to read a native Excel file into code designed to process a CSV file. They're not the same thing.

If you want to read it as CSV, export it from Excel as such. If you want to read a Native Excel file, look at the PHPExcel library.

Answer (score 0):

First, those are not errors, but [notices](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) telling you there is no N'th element in the `$filesop` array.

Second, I do not think you can read an XLSX file with `fgetcsv`, you will need an external library for that ([PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) for example).

Third, you are `INSERT`ing into `csv`, while the name of your table is `fund_balances`.

Furthermore, this: `"$hostname"` is useless, just use `$hostname`.

Finally, read up on [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).